# Filter Wrapper Class and display result in VF Page

Tags: apex, visualforce, wrapper-class

I am trying to filter the result of a Wrapper class. For example, I have a list that populates a table with 3 rows but I would like to display the same table filtered based on Name which it should only display 1 row. I can't display these value in the page. I will appreciate any help!

Error: Unknown property 'String.Name' in Visualforce page while saving

Controller:

```
 filterResult = new List<String>(); 
  for(MyWrapper s : wrappedObjects){                                            
    if(s.Cont.Name == 'Cart-1')
     {
       filterResult.add(String.valueof(s));
       System.debug(filterResult);                            
     }                                               
  }
```

System.debug:

```
 USER_DEBUG [185]|DEBUG|(Container__c:{Id=a1Rf0000000n20eEAA, Name=cart1 - A1})
```

Page:

```
 <apex:repeat value="{!filterResult}" var="c" > 
     Container Id:       
     <apex:outputText value="{!c.Id}" /> 
     Container:       
     <apex:outputText value="{!c.Name}" />        
  </apex:repeat>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of having filterResult as `List<String>` you can have it as `List<MyWrapper>`.

```
filterResult = new List<MyWrapper>();
for(MyWrapper s : wrappedObjects){                      
    if(s.Cont.Name == 'Cart-1')
    {
        filterResult.add(s);
        System.debug(filterResult);
    }                                               
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Vigneshwaran G,  thank you so much! that made it :) have a great weekend!